ClearCollect in powerapps missing column data
Filtering inside ClearCollect doesn't return all the list of columns from the original collection of table.
ClearCollect(MyCollection, Filter(OriginalCollection, isActive = true))


It's related caching of collection. Before re-use the collection, it's better to refresh the collection at first.
Clear(MyCollection);
ClearCollect(MyCollection, Filter(OriginalCollection, isActive = true))

